# Anyobject to string when appending an array

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to get the name in the `textLabel` of the first cell that is being checked in my `tableView`, but I can't seem to get the `AnyObject` converted to a string. My error says:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and it appears in the last line of my code.

```
var stringList = [String]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let mySelectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    if (mySelectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark) {
        mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None           
    }
    else {
        mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        mySelectedCell.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        if let tx = mySelectedCell.textLabel?.text as Optional{

            stringList.append(tx)}
         }        
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destVC: AddFriendViewController = segue.destinationViewController as AddFriendViewController

        destVC.viewOut.text! = stringList[0] as String
}
```

Any thoughts on how to proceed would be appreciated.

**EDIT: The destination VC's code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var viewOut: UITextField!

var viewer:String = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewOut.text = viewer

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

**EDIT 2: By replacing the `prepareForSegue` function I got rid of my error, but the label still doesn't show any text.**

```
func friendAdded(){

    var destVC: AddFriendViewController = AddFriendViewController()
        destVC.viewer = stringList[0]    
}
```

Comment: my thought is that destVC's viewOut isn't currently initialized and therefore you're getting nil

Comment: @chris I've added the code for the destination VC too.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "by replacing the `prepareForSegue` function", as you then proceed to show us a `friendAdded` method that makes no sense at all. You should keep your `prepareForSegue` method, but simply change it so it sets `viewer` rather than `viewOut.text`. Don't perform the segue automatically (but rather trigger it programmatically in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`), but you need to keep `prepareForSegue` method that sets `viewer` in destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You cannot have your source controller try to access an `IBOutlet` of the destination. By the time `prepareForSegue` is called, the controls referenced by the IB outlets have not created yet, so `viewOut` is undoubtedly still `nil`.

   So, rather than having `prepareForSegue` do the following:

   ```
   destVC.viewOut.text! = stringList[0] as String
   ```

   It should instead just set the `String` property, `viewer`:

   ```
   destVC.viewer = stringList[0]
   ```

   And then the `viewDidLoad` of the destination would then populate the `UITextField` control called `viewOut` from the `String` called `viewer`:

   ```
   viewOut.text = viewer
   ```
2. It's not entirely clear from your code sample, but it would appear that you might have both a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method as well as a segue going from the cell to the destination view controller. (I'm guessing this because I don't see anything here that is programmatically initiating the segue.)

   If so, that's a problem, because the segue may be performed *before* `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called (i.e. you'll see `prepareForSegue` called before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`). To solve this, remove the segue from the cell to the next scene, but instead have the segue between the two scenes themselves. (I.e. make it so the segue is not invoked automatically when you select the cell.) If you give that segue a unique storyboard id, you can then invoke it programmatically from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       let mySelectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
       if let tx = mySelectedCell.textLabel?.text as String? {
           stringList.append(tx)
       }

       performSegueWithIdentifier("yourseguestoryboardidhere", sender: self)
   }
   ```
3. This is a bit more academic (and unrelated to the problem at hand), but you generally should not retrieve the text to be passed to the next scene from the cell. You really should go back to your model.

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of the error, but the label still doesn't show any name, it's just empty, do you have any idea why? I've posted my edited code above.

Comment: I did the above and it worked fine, so there's got to be something simple wrong in your implementation. Just put in debugging messages all over the place (in `didSelect`, `prepareSegue`, in the destination's `viewDidLoad`, etc.) and figure out where precisely it's going awry. There are just too many points of possible errors to be guessing randomly. Also, did you make the change so that `didSelect` invokes the segue programmatically, rather than automatically?

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been very helpful. I need to wrap my head around the things you just mentioned, because there are a some things I'm not quite familiar with yet. That being said, I'm sure your information is more than enough when I get my understanding in place. Thank you again!